# How to convert to AVAudioPCMBuffer from AudioBufferList?

Tags: ios, swift, audio, core-audio

i am struggling to convert it.

I made `AudioBufferList` data using `AudioUnit` with refer [This](https://gist.github.com/hotpaw2/ba815fc23b5d642705f2b1dedfaf0107).

And It has filled audio buffer data by `AudioUnitRender()`.

```swift
       var bufferList = AudioBufferList(
           mNumberBuffers: 1,
           mBuffers: AudioBuffer(
               mNumberChannels: UInt32(2),
               mDataByteSize: 16,
               mData: nil))
   
       
       if let au = audioObject.audioUnit {
           err = AudioUnitRender(au,
                                 ioActionFlags,
                                 inTimeStamp,
                                 inBusNumber,
                                 frameCount,
                                 &bufferList)
       }
```

And then, I tried to convert it to `AudioBufferList`.
But, It doesn't work

Following is what i did.

```swift
        let audioFormat = AVAudioFormat(
            commonFormat: AVAudioCommonFormat.pcmFormatFloat64,
            sampleRate: recoder.sampleRate,
            interleaved: false,
            channelLayout: AVAudioChannelLayout(
                layoutTag: kAudioChannelLayoutTag_Stereo
            )!
        )

        guard let pcmBuffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(
                    pcmFormat: audioFormat,
                    bufferListNoCopy: &bufferList
                ) else {
                    return
                }
```

A console message i received.

```
AVAudioBuffer.mm:248   the number of buffers (1) does not match the format's number of channel streams (2)
```

Please help me someone

thank you.

Comment: The `AudioBufferList` you create has `mNumberBuffers = 1` and the single contained `AudioBuffer` has `mNumberChannels = 2` so overall the buffer list contains two interleaved channels. The `AVAudioFormat` you're creating is non-interleaved stereo which is why you're seeing the format mismatch error. You can try creating a non-interleaved `AVAudioFormat` or use `AVAudioConverter` to deinterleave the data.

Comment: @sbooth thank you for answer! It's works after i had change `interleaved: false` to `interleaved: true` with your answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AudioBufferList` you create has `mNumberBuffers = 1` and the single contained `AudioBuffer` has `mNumberChannels = 2` so overall the buffer list contains two interleaved channels. The `AVAudioFormat` you're creating is non-interleaved stereo which is why you're seeing the format mismatch error. You can try creating a non-interleaved `AVAudioFormat` or use `AVAudioConverter` to deinterleave the data.